# Is there a way to set a flag when using argparse so the user can input arguments in any order?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have implemented argparse into my Python script.
Currently a user has to input the arguments into the command line in the same order in which they are called in the script.

Is there a way to specify a 'flag' to an input such that the user can input the args in any order in the command line, if they use a flag to specify which arg they are providing?

e.g. I want 
function.py input2=x input4=z input1=v input3=y?

instead of 
function.py v x y z

Comment: To input arguments in any order, use the prefix character to indicate flags, e.g `function.py --input2 x --input4 z`, what the docs call `optionals`.  You are using `positionals`, which have a defined order.  `argparse` is the wrong parser for dealing with your `input2=x` syntax.

Comment: You could accept strings like 'input2=x', and handle them after parsing.  Just split on '=' and create a dictionary.  `argparse` won't handle that for you.